# macOS Big Sur new toolbar button style

Tags: swift, xcode, macos-big-sur

When I create an App with SwiftUI App Lifecycle the toolbar buttons match with the new Big Sur toolbar button style (with onHover effect style). But if I choose the conventional AppDelegate Lifecycle and customize the toolbar via Storyboards then I get this button style without onHover effect:

[image]

The button appears with a rectangle as background. Does anyone know how could I achieve the new style?

Answer (score 10):

I've got this effect after I set `NSButton.showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside` property.

```
button.setButtonType(.momentaryPushIn)
button.isBordered = true
button.showsBorderOnlyWhileMouseInside = true
```

[image: result]

Comment: This worked for me in Xcode 12.4 and macOS 11.2.3, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

`toolbarItem.isBordered = true`

`isBordered` property will give you that hover effect.

Comment: This gives hover effect only for images. When you have image+text it looks ugly.

Answer (score 3):

I've just had this problem myself and found the following NSButton settings to work.

```
Button style = Textured Rounded  
Type = Momentary Light
```

Comment: It didn't work for me :/ I'm getting a bordered button without background if the button have label (but if the button have only an image, it works).

Comment: Yeah I'm seeing the same thing in macOS 11.0 Beta 3 (20A5323l). Works with icons, not if you add text. Mail has a "Move to…" button with an icon which does react to hover so I suspect this is a bug and not intentional. I'd log it using Feedback Assistant.

Comment: I just created a bug report using the Feedback Assistant - this seems like a bug to me.

Comment: You need `isBordered` ticked as well, otherwise the icon itself will highlight, not a rounded background.